# Set width-height-left-top dynamically in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I'm trying to set size and position of dynamically generated elements with jQuery or inline css, but Safari just doesn't use it.

This is the example for jQuery:

```
$("#e"+i).css("width", var1).css("height", var1).css("left", varcleft+'px').css("top", -(varleft/2)+'px').css("z-index", var1);
```

**NOTE:** I'm using the `+"px"` because positions are previously set with percentages.
As a matter of fact, the inline version works for all browsers except Safari. The jQuery version, only in Chrome.

I use something similar for inline style, but Safari still ignore it.
Any ideas on how to make that work in Safari?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to set all of the target elements with a common class name, and target that class instead?

Comment: Is it possible to change class values with js? Sorry if this is pretty simple, I just didn't know

Answer (score 0):

Combine all styles into one. Try like this.

```
  $("#e"+i).css({'width':var1,'height':var1,'left': varcleft+'px','top':-(varleft/2)+'px','z-index':var1});
```